# How to highlight search-matching text on a web page

Tags: php, regex, search, pattern-matching, preg-replace

I'm trying to write a PHP function that takes some text to be displayed on a web page, and then based on some entered search terms, highlights the corresponding parts of the text. Unfortunately, I'm having a couple of issues.
To better explain the two issues I'm having, let's imagine that the following innocuous string is being searched on and will be displayed on the web page:

```
My daughter was born on January 11, 2011.
```

My first problem is that if more than one search term is entered, any placeholder text I use to mark the start and end of any matches for the first term may then be matched by the second term.
For example, I'm currently using the following delimiting strings to mark the beginning and end of a match (upon which I use the `preg_replace` function at the end of the function to turn the delimiters into HTML `span` tags):

```
'#####highlightStart#####'
'#####highlightEnd#####'
```

The problem is, if I do a search like `2011 light`, then `2011` will be matched first, giving me:

```
My daughter was born on January 11, #####highlightStart#####2011#####highlightEnd#####.
```

Upon which when `light` is searched for, it will match the word `light` within both `#####highlightStart#####` and `#####highlightEnd#####`, which I don't want.

One thought I had was to create some really obscure delimiting strings (in perhaps a foreign language) that would likely never be searched on, but I can't guarantee that any particular string will never be searched on and it just seems like a really kludgy solution. Basically, I imagine that there is a better way to do it.
Any advice on this first point would be greatly appreciated.

My second question has to do with how to handle overlapping matches.
For example, with the same string `My daughter was born on January 11, 2011.`, if the entered search is `Jan anuar`, then `Jan` will be matched first, giving me:

```
My daughter was born on #####highlightStart#####Jan#####highlightEnd#####uary 11, 2011.
```

And because the delimiting text is now a part of the string, the second search term, `anuar` will never be matched.

Regarding this issue, I am quite perplexed and really have no clue how to solve it.
I feel like I need to somehow do all of the search operations on the original string separately and then somehow combine them at the end, but again, I'm lost on how to do this.
Perhaps there's a way better solution altogether, but I don't know what that would be.

Any advice or direction on how to solve either or both of these problems would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case I think it's simpler to use `str_replace` (though it won't be perfect).

Assuming you've got an array of terms you want to highlight, I'll call it `$aSearchTerms` for the sake of argument... and that wrapping the highlighted terms in the HTML5 `<mark>` tag is acceptable (for the sake of legibility, you've stated it's going on a web-page and it's easy to `strip_tags()` from your search terms):

```
$aSearchTerms = ['Jan', 'anu', 'Feb', '11'];
$sinContent = "My daughter was born on January 11, 2011.";

foreach($aSearchTerms as $sinTerm) {
    $sinContent = str_replace($sinTerm, "<mark>{$sinTerm}</mark>", $sinContent);
}

echo $sinContent;
// outputs: My d<mark>au</mark>ghter was born on <mark>Jan</mark>uary <mark>11</mark>, 20<mark>11</mark>.
```

It's not perfect since, using the data in that array, the first pass will change `January` to `<mark>Jan</mark>uary` which means `anu` will no longer match in *J**anu**ary* - something like this will, however, cover *most* usage needs.

---

**EDIT**

Oki - I'm not 100% certain this is sane but I took a totally different approach looking at the link @AlexAtNet posted:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3631016/886824

What I've done is looked at the points in the string where the search term is found numerically (the indexes) and built an array of start and end indexes where the `<mark>` and `</mark>` tags are going to be entered.

Then using the answer above merged those start and end indexes together - this covers your overlapping matches issue.

Then I've looped that array and cut the original string up into substrings and glued it back together inserting the `<mark>` and `</mark>` tags at the relevant points (based on the indexes). This should cover your second issue so you're not having string replacements replacing string replacements.

The code in full looks like:

```
<?php
$sContent = "Captain's log, January 11, 2711 - Uranus";
$ainSearchTerms = array('Jan', 'asduih', 'anu', '11');

//lower-case it for substr_count
$sContentForSearching = strtolower($sContent);

//array of first and last positions of the terms within the string
$aTermPositions = array();

//loop through your search terms and build a multi-dimensional array
//of start and end indexes for each term
foreach($ainSearchTerms as $sinTerm) {

  //lower-case the search term
  $sinTermLower = strtolower($sinTerm);

  $iTermPosition = 0;
  $iTermLength = strlen($sinTermLower);
  $iTermOccursCount = substr_count($sContentForSearching, $sinTermLower);

  for($i=0; $i<$iTermOccursCount; $i++) {

    //find the start and end positions for this term
    $iStartIndex = strpos($sContentForSearching, $sinTermLower, $iTermPosition);
    $iEndIndex = $iStartIndex + $iTermLength;
    $aTermPositions[] = array($iStartIndex, $iEndIndex);

    //update the term position
    $iTermPosition = $iEndIndex + $i;
  }
}

//taken directly from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/3631016/886824
//just replaced $data with $aTermPositions
//this sorts out the overlaps so that 'Jan' and 'anu' will merge into 'Janu'
//in January - whilst still matching 'anu' in Uranus
//
//This conveniently sorts all your start and end indexes in ascending order
usort($aTermPositions, function($a, $b)
{
        return $a[0] - $b[0];
});

$n = 0; $len = count($aTermPositions);
for ($i = 1; $i < $len; ++$i)
{
        if ($aTermPositions[$i][0] > $aTermPositions[$n][1] + 1)
                $n = $i;
        else
        {
                if ($aTermPositions[$n][1] < $aTermPositions[$i][1])
                        $aTermPositions[$n][1] = $aTermPositions[$i][1];
                unset($aTermPositions[$i]);
        }
}

$aTermPositions = array_values($aTermPositions);

//finally chop your original string into the bits
//where you want to insert <mark> and </mark>
if($aTermPositions) {
    $iLastContentChunkIndex = 0;
    $soutContent = "";

    foreach($aTermPositions as $aChunkIndex) {
        $soutContent .= substr($sContent, $iLastContentChunkIndex, $aChunkIndex[0] - $iLastContentChunkIndex)
            . "<mark>" . substr($sContent, $aChunkIndex[0], $aChunkIndex[1] - $aChunkIndex[0]) . "</mark>";

        $iLastContentChunkIndex = $aChunkIndex[1];
    }

    //... and the bit on the end
    $soutContent .= substr($sContent, $iLastContentChunkIndex);
}

//this *should* output the following:
//Captain's log, <mark>Janu</mark>ary <mark>11</mark>, 27<mark>11</mark> - Ur<mark>anu</mark>s
echo $soutContent;
```

**The inevitable gotcha!**
Using this on content that's already HTML may fail horribly.

Given the string.

`In <a href="#">January</a> this year...`

A search/mark of `Jan` will insert the `<mark>/</mark>` around 'Jan' which is fine. However a search mark of something like `In Jan` is going to fail as there's markup in the way :\

Can't think of a good way around that I'm afraid.

Comment: CD001, I appreciate your answer, but that's pretty much what I already have, and with that solution, I have the two issues above. Also, one thing you didn't note is that if one of the search terms in your array was `'mark'` (which is not hard to believe), then you would basically have the same problem I described in issue #1.

Comment: Honestly I'd probably ignore overlapping matches... but it could probably be dealt with with a recursive function. You're point about `mark` as a search term definitely stands though... could `preg_replace()` looking at the term if it's not already wrapped like `> ... <` but that's getting dangerously close to parsing HTML with RegExps! I'll have a proper think about it when I get home if nobody else has answered by then... currently waiting for an SVN synch to finish before leaving work.

Comment: No biggie. It is a hard problem to solve and I couldn't find any other answers on SO, which is why I asked it. AlexAtNet seems to have given me a good lead on the second (the overlapping matches) issue at least.

Comment: I ended up coming up with a similar solution on my own, but yours looks fine too, so thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Do not modify original string and store the matches in the individual array, either starts in odd and ends in even elements or store them in records (arrays of two items).

After searching for the several keywords, you end up with several arrays with matches. So the task now is how to merge two lists of segments, producing the segments that covers the areas. As the lists are sorted, this is a trivial task that can be solved in O(n) time.

Then just insert highlight tokens into positions recorded in the resulting array.

Comment: Alex, I appreciate the answer, and I think that from a high-level, I conceptually understand what you're getting at, but a bit of sample code would be incredibly helpful. Thank you.

Comment: It is not exactly PHP, but quite similar: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/merging-intervals/

Comment: PHP: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3630500/merging-overlapping-ranges-in-php-arrays

Comment: Both helpful comments, but they both deal with only numbers. How do I calculate the overlap between two strings?

Comment: The idea is that these intervals are positions in the string. So, for example, you search for "b" keyword in a string "aabbcc" by invoking preg_match with PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE. This gives you array of matches with indices (offsets) for every match. By adding match length to its offset you will get the array of intervals like there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3630500/merging-overlapping-ranges-in-php-arrays. Do it for all keywords in search query and then merge.

Comment: That's a good idea. I will have to play with it a bit, and then I'll get back to you. Thank you. Any ideas on how to solve the first problem related to not matching text within the delimiters?

Comment: As the search happens in unmodified string, there will be no such problem. First: search for all keywords in unmodified strings and build arrays. Second: merge intervals. Third: insert delimiters. As you search on the first step only, you search in unmodified string all the time.

Comment: BTW, I assume that you add delimiters to insert highlighting tags so on the third step what you actually can insert the formatting tags, like @CD001 suggested. Generally, you do not need intermediate delimiters at all with this approach.