# PHP Get uptime periods from array of overlapping Incidents

Tags: php, logic, uptime

**Solution:**

I looked at this:
[Merging overlapping ranges in PHP arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3630500/merging-overlapping-ranges-in-php-arrays?noredirect=1&lq=1)

and solved my problem in this example:
https://3v4l.org/XCtlT

**Non-working code example here:**
https://3v4l.org/sStTT

Essentially, i have an array of overlapping downtime incidents that looks like this:

```
$incidents = [
  ['start' => '2016-01-05 00:00:00', 'end' => '2016-01-10 23:59:59'],
  ['start' => '2016-01-07 00:00:00', 'end' => '2016-01-15 23:59:59'], // overlapping
  ['start' => '2016-01-12 00:00:00', 'end' => '2016-01-13 23:59:59'], // overlapping
  ['start' => '2016-01-20 00:00:00', 'end' => '2016-01-25 23:59:59'],
  ['start' => '2016-01-23 00:00:00', 'end' => '2016-01-24 23:59:59']  // overlapping
];
```

And from the incidents-array i expect to get the result below as an uptime array.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [start] => 2016-01-01 00:00:00
            [end] => 2016-01-05 00:00:00
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [start] => 2016-01-15 23:59:59
            [end] => 2016-01-20 00:00:00
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [start] => 2016-01-25 23:59:59
            [end] => 2016-01-31 23:59:59
        )
)
```

Unfortunately my logic game is not good enough to complete the task reliably and efficient enough. In real example i have about 2.5 million rows of incidents in a DB.

What are your thoughts on using 2 for loops to calculate uptime?

Is there more efficient / easier ways to do this?

Are you able to complete the logic so the uptime result is working as intended?

Comment: One point to note: if possible, you should really consider using [start, end) format for your datetime ranges (inclusive start, exclusive end). It will make the algorithm much simpler when trying to work out that `2016-01-25 00:00:00 -> 2016-01-25 23:59:59` is contiguous to `2016-01-26 00:00:00 -> 2016-01-26 23:59:59` for instance.

Answer (score 0):

There are four steps to an algorithm like this:

1. Filter the incidents to those that overlap your report date range
2. Sort the incidents by incident start
3. Merge all incidents into contiguous blocks (`O(n)` operation)
4. Invert these ranges by returning the gaps between merged incidents (`O(n)` operation)

Steps 1 and 2 can be simply handled in the database query, such as:

```
select    start, end
from      incidents
where     start < :reportEnd and
          end   > :reportStart
order by  start
```